# Add symlinks to git repository

Tags: git

I'm working on a little library and it depends on another github project.

I know that
[some projects](http://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9/tree/1b1401f/support)
add symlinks. How exactly do you do that?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link)

Comment: Thanks for the link but that doesn't really explain how to DO it, just what happens if you have it.  For example, Do I just check out the dependency project to a subdirectory of my project and boom it works?

Comment: Sorry, I read too quickly and missed the part about depending on another github project.  I don't have an answer.

Comment: Your example link is broken.  Perhaps you can link to a specific commit of that project?  I was not able to find anything relevant quickly using GitHub's advanced search function.  Maybe there's a trick.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you'll want to use are [git submodules](http://help.github.com/submodules/).

Example: `git submodule add git://github.com/user/project.git destination-dir/`

Comment: This is a good guide that covers basic submodule usage: http://codingsnippets.com/getting-started-with-git/

Comment: Note however, that this works if the other code has is own git repo. Otherwise, a symlink solution works great, like this [Shared models between two Rails apps - what is the ideal solution for Workflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024741/shared-models-between-two-rails-apps-what-is-the-ideal-solution-for-workflow)